# print all nested member variables of a struct with a generic function call

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, c++17

Let's say, I have the following nested struct definition,

```
struct C {
    int r;
    char s;
};
struct B {
    int p;
    char q;
    C c;
};
struct A {
    int x;
    int y;
    B b;
    char z;
};
```

I need a `pretty_print(A &a)` function which prints all the member variables with proper indentation. I could do it in the following way:

```
#include <iostream>
struct C {
    int r;
    char s;
};
struct B {
    int p;
    char q;
    C c;
};
struct A {
    int x;
    int y;
    B b;
    char z;
};

void pretty_print(A &a) {
    std::cout << a.x << std::endl;
    std::cout << a.y << std::endl;
    std::cout <<"\t"<< a.b.p << std::endl;
    std::cout <<"\t"<< a.b.q << std::endl;
    std::cout <<"\t\t"<< a.b.c.r << std::endl;
    std::cout <<"\t\t"<< a.b.c.s << std::endl;
    std::cout << a.z << std::endl;

}
int main() {
    A a{1, 2, {3, 'p', {4, 'k'}}, 'w'};
    pretty_print(a);
}
```

Is there a way to have a member (or non-member) function (generic function, written only once) that takes struct A and automatically figures out its member variables and prints them with proper indentation? (basically, the required function definition should not change if we change the type of member variable or add or remove member variables)

Thanks!

Comment: Not portably.  C++ does not have reflection (yet).

Comment: Looks just like what [Boost.PFR](http://apolukhin.github.io/magic_get/index.html) (not actually officially in Boost yet) does, as long as all of your classes are aggregates.

Comment: @Quentin can you elaborate it in an answer? That would be helpful. thanks!

Comment: @Debashish I cannot right now, but it looks like recursive use of `boost::pfr::for_each_field` should be enough to traverse your object.

Comment: @Quentin: This is a C++14 library too, whereas OP tags C++11.

Comment: @Jarod42, are you saying this could be done using `c++14` feature?

Comment: @Jarod42 oops, my bad.

Comment: @Debashish: As state in the links, with some restrictions on your classes, yes. (it was originally [magic_get](https://github.com/apolukhin/magic_get)).

Comment: Update: I too implemented something to reflect structures recently. 
https://github.com/ddeka0/cppLearn/tree/master/struct_serialization/final

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there was a way to iterate over the data members of plain structs then the solution to your problem would be easy. The buzzword for that kind of functionality is *(static) reflection*. However, the **C++ language does not offer reflection** facilities (yet).

In some special cases (and starting from C++14) there exist **hacks that provide some level of reflection**. A proof of concept is given in [Boost.PFR (ex magic_get)](https://github.com/apolukhin/magic_get). Note that it is has not (yet?) been approved as an official part of Boost. The underlying techniques are also explained in [this conference talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=abdeAew3gmQ).

Alternatively, you can build your own reflection tools by **annotating your structs with meta-information** on their layout. Examples in Boost are found in [Boost.Fusion](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_69_0/libs/fusion/doc/html/fusion/adapted/adapt_struct.html) and [Boost.Hana](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_69_0/libs/hana/doc/html/index.html#tutorial-introspection-adapting). Other approaches use external code generation tools (see, e.g., [siplasplas](https://manu343726.github.io/siplasplas/) (discontinued?) or [Qt's Meta-Object System](http://doc.qt.io/archives/4.6/metaobjects.html)).

Finally, in your minimal example there is a simple way to print the aggregates if you can **turn the plain structs into tuples**.

```
static_assert(__cplusplus >= 201703L, "example written for C++17 or later");

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <tuple>
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

using CMembers = std::tuple<int, char>;
struct C : CMembers {
  using Members = CMembers;
  using Members::Members;// inherit constructor
};

using BMembers = std::tuple<int, char, C>;
struct B : BMembers {
  using Members = BMembers;
  using Members::Members;// inherit constructor
};

using AMembers = std::tuple<int, int, B, char>;
struct A : AMembers {
  using Members = AMembers;
  using Members::Members;// inherit constructor
};



template<std::size_t... is, class... Ts, class F>
void foreach_tuple_element(
  std::index_sequence<is...>,
  const std::tuple<Ts...>& tuple,
  F f
) {
  ( f( std::get<is>(tuple) ), ... );
}

template<class... Ts, class F>
void foreach_tuple_element(
  const std::tuple<Ts...>& tuple,
  F f
) {
  foreach_tuple_element(std::index_sequence_for<Ts...>{}, tuple, f);
}



template<class T>
auto pretty_print(const T& x, std::string indent = "")
  -> std::void_t<decltype(std::cout << indent << x << "\n")>
{
  std::cout << indent << x << "\n";
}

template<class... Ts>
void pretty_print(const std::tuple<Ts...>& tuple, std::string indent = "") {
  foreach_tuple_element(tuple, [indent] (auto&& x) {
    pretty_print(x, indent + "\t");
  });
}

template<class T, class MemberTuple = typename T::Members>
void pretty_print(const T& x, std::string indent = "") {
  pretty_print(static_cast<const MemberTuple&>(x), indent);
}



int main() {
    A a{1, 2, {3, 'p', {4, 'k'}}, 'w'};
    pretty_print(a);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not currently, no. This would require reflection, and C++ has no good way to do that yet.

You can get somewhat further if you accept additional preprocessing funkiness (see e.g. https://bytemaster.github.io/boost_reflect/index.html), but you cannot do it directly from an existing struct definition without repeating the members.

Comment: Thanks! Can you provide a simple example using boost library?

Comment: @Debashish Sorry, I haven't used the library before. Since it's not an official boost library, it's not available on godbolt.org either, so I can't do more than point you to the documentation.